# Flask multiple login from same computer

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-security

I currently have a flask application that uses Flask-Security to handle user login and registration. I'm trying to test a chatroom I made so I want to login to two different accounts in different windows to check if it works. However I can't do that because when I login to account2 it simply logs out account1 in my other browser. I'm certain this has something to do with Flask-Login and user sessions but I'm not sure how to fix this issue. If anyone could point me in the right direction that'd be awesome.

I tried looking at the LoginManger docs on Flask-Login's site but can't figure out how to disable cookies.

Comment: It should be problem with Flask-Security as one of its features is to store session ip address. In that case, even different computers using same ip address should have problem. I used Flask-Login without Flask-Security 2-3 month ago and used multiple accounts over Private Tab and different browsers.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. I tried to disable "SECURITY_TRACKABLE" in Flask-Security but that didn't help. Seems unfortunate if there's no way to fix that. Not sure why there's not a way because it is pretty important to test your website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the same type of browser to try and log into different accounts. Such as two firefox browsers and I tried two firefox incognito browsers. Which in both cases I think they shared the same cookies. After trying with one Chrome and one Firefox it worked correctly.